# How do I find a protein from this DNA sequence?

Tags: dna, proteins, dna-sequencing

I have a DNA sequence from a sequencer. How can I determine what protein is it? I tried some translator but it didn't help. What protein is this and how can I determine it?

The sequence: **CGTTCTATAGATACGCGATGACGGTATACCATCCGCAAAGT**

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried to blast the sequence?

Comment: Translation would fail on this sequence since it’s not a complete open reading frame (doesn’t start with a start codon, doesn’t stop with a stop codon, and length not divisible by three). As such, we don’t even know whether it’s in frame, or maybe shifted by a nucleotide.

Comment: Entering fragment in BLASTX helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter it in [BLASTX.](http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PROGRAM=blastx&PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&LINK_LOC=blasthome) This will give you any protein sequence matches as well as likely homologues given a nucleotide sequence.

Comment: Great, I hope that was good news for you!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try searching against NR/NT database using [BLAST](http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi). This way you will get to know what this sequence might be similar too. The length of the sequence is too short to code for any meaningful protein.